# Is it possible to set state.loggedIn before loading the page and before guest middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js

I set up `@nuxtjs/auth` and guest middleware. But if I'm logged in and I restart the browser and go to `/login` endpoint I can access the page because `state.loggedIn` is set only after the page is loaded. Is it possible to set `state.loggedIn` before middleware and page load?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES.

You can use nuxtServerInit to check the request's connection status before returning the server rendering page.

in `store/index.js`

```
actions: {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user) {
      commit('user', req.session.user)
    }
  }
}
```

reference link: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action